# Rails 3.1 - migrating dev from mySQL to PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku

Till recently i've needed to run the dev environment for my Heroku (postgres) app on mySQL.

Obviously this is not ideal (running dev and production on different dbs) and, as the original restriction has been taken away, i'm looking for the best strategy/instruction-set for moving my dev environment over to postgres and either migrating the mySQL data across, or pulling the production data into the new dev db.

What is the best route?

Thanks in advance for any help or direction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best bet is to take the simple route.

- Install postgres
- Setup your local codebase to look at the new
  database
- `rake db:setup`
- `heroku db:pull --app <your production app>`